# Change the second element in a List of Lists based one the first

Tags: python

This is what is my list of lists

```
[['a', '0'], ['b', '0'], ['c', '0'], ['d', '0']]
```

What I am aiming to do is to make the second element of the secondary list change to a 1 when the first element is equal to a input.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please show your current attempts based on your research and explain why they didn't do as you expected

Comment: Could you also post sample input and output as well ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access list element by explicitly providing its index.

```
list = [['a', '0'], ['b', '0'], ['c', '0'], ['d', '0']]
input = raw_input("Input: ")
#Input: b
if input == list[1][0]:
     list[1][1] = '1'

print(list)
# Outputs: [['a', '0'], ['b', '1'], ['c', '0'], ['d', '0']]
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to mirror built-ins like that. Don't name variables `list` or `input`.